# There's any way to change the column name on SHOW TABLES?

Tags: mysql, show

I need to make the following Query on VB.NET to a MySQL Server

```
SHOW TABLES FROM BaseX
```

Currently returns "Tables_in_BaseX"
But I want that the column name be a specific word.
There's any way to change it?

Example:

```
Tables_in_BaseX <--Column name/title
Clients
Data
Info
Schedule
```

Should be

```
BaseX Table list <--Column name/title
Clients
Data
Info
Schedule
```

I tried

```
SHOW TABLES FROM BaseX AS 'BaseX Table list';
```

But didn't work

Comment: confusing.  can you show some sample expected output?

Comment: Added more info/example.

Comment: I have similar issue, any luck on solving this ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL? What OS?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `information_schema.tables` instead:

```
select table_name as 'BaseX Table List'
from information_schema.tables t
where t.table_schema = 'BaseX'
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't.schema_name' in 'where clause'